# Loading all the contents of a file into individual files respectively

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file with Employee Data "Emp.txt"

```
EMPNO   ENAME    JOB        MGR      SAL    COMM  DEPTNO  Date

7499     ALLEN    SALESMAN    7698   1600    300    30     Null

.....(more 50 records)........
```

I want to load every record into new file saved as "Empno.Ename". Script also should check whether file exists in the path before it creates. If exists the script should read the data in the file and update Date Column with Current Timestamp.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you trying to use? 
Take a look at the question guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

i think you could try awk for something like this.
how about something like this?:

```
awk '{x=$2; print > x}' file.txt
```

You can also format your output further as well.

Comment: i've assumed the first field of your file as the new filename, but you can change this if you like

Comment: Look at the votes for the first comment to the original question. Generally SO is here to help with problems -- not provide a coding service. It's hard to know what the OP has tried if they don't provide any code of a previous attempt. A careful read of the question also discloses "*into new file saved as "Empno.Ename"*", so you might want to incorporate a `$2` into your answer.

Comment: updated, i suppose it could be a guide for the OP to find a complete solution for his query :)

Comment: I assumed the "Empno.Ename" would take both`$1` and `$2`.

Comment: something like this could work:

`awk '{x=$1"."$2; print  > x}'  Emp.txt`

The Op can further enhance the code to add headers and timpestamps and check if a file exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Using POSIX Shell**

You can begin with a very trivial read of the file, reading values into a `num`, `name` and the rest of the line into a `rest` variable, then validate that each variable is not empty and redirect the complete line into a file made up of `"$num.$name"`. A simple loop is all that is required:

```
while read -r num name rest; do
    if test -n "$num" -a -n "$name" -a -n "$rest"
    then
        echo "$num $name $rest" > "$num.$name"
    fi
done < filename
```

(if your version of `read` doesn't have `-r`, just omit it)

You can also add a counter to skip any heading lines if that is desired. If you need to preserve *whitespace* you can read the entire line into a single variable (e.g. `$line`) and then parse `num` and `name` from `$line` using *parameter expansion with substring removal* and perform your validations, then write the original `$line` out to the filename created from `"$num.$name"`.

**Using AWK**

You can do the same thing using `awk`. To combine the `num` and `name` fields into a single variable, you can use, e.g. `x=$1"."$2`. To then write each line into a separate `num.name` file, you could use something similar to:

```
awk '{x=$1"."$2; print > x}' filename
```

`awk` also has provisions for skipping header rows, etc..